# flashbuilderX -> FlexX or something

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I'm not sure in which direction you would do this; but since Adobe Flash Builder is the "application" and Flex is the "framework" for actionscript (the "language")... what would you do with the tags?

- Should all exist? (`Program`, `framework`, and `language`?)
- Should use of (`Program`) be discouraged when the question relates to (`framework`)?